# How do I join this community?

Tags: discussion

While searching Dharmic topics on internet, I found this site very helpful. So, I want to join and contribute to this site. How do I join here? And what does "Beta" mean in the title of site "Hinduism Beta"?

Comment: Hello and Welcome to Hinduism.SE. Thanks for your interest :). Hopefully, someone will answer your post soon. (To other users: _already flagged to migrate to meta_)

Comment: Welcome. You can click sign up and follow the steps as instructed and join this community. You can register using your e-mail,id, facebook account, google+ account and yahoo. To know what is beta, See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-beta). Or visit help center for other clarifications.

Comment: @SwiftPushkar I am not sure either.

Comment: @iammilind nope this account is unregistered one.

Comment: I hope this user does't join HNQ list.

Answer (score 9):

You can join this community by creating or registering account.

As you've posted one question as [Unregistered User](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/68524/260388), you can complete process of creating account as [follows](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/42270/260388):

> **Click the "register" link at the top of the page.**
>
> If you do not hold the browser cookie to your unregistered account, visit the login page and click "forgot your login info?" (Note that you must have have voluntarily provided an email address to us at some point for cookie recovery to work -- we do not require email.)

Visit the help center on [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/creating-accounts) topic:

> #### How do I create an account?
>
> To create an account on Hinduism Stack Exchange, please [sign up through Google, Facebook, or create a new Stack Exchange account](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/login) using an email address and password.

I recommend you visiting Help Center to learn some essentials:

- [How do I ask a good question?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)
- [How do I write a good answer?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

---

Talking about **`Beta`**, visit [What does "beta" mean?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/whats-beta) and [Area51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/53689/hinduism).